# Criteria Query Using Left Join, Custom Wrapper, and Dynamic search terms

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria-api

I have 2 entities Product and Review and 1 interface ReviewItem

```py
@Entity
public class Product
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long productid;

    private String productname;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "reviewedProduct")
    private Set<Review> productReviews;
    ... constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```py
@Entity
public class Review
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long reviewid;

    Integer stars;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productid")
    private Product reviewedProduct;
    ... constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```py
public interface ReviewItem
{
    long getProductid();

    String getProductname();

    Double getAvgRating();

    Integer getReviewCount();
}
```

In short, I am trying to write a Criteria Query that looks like:

```py
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, AVG(r.stars) AS avgRating, 
COUNT(r.productid) AS reviewCount 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN reviews r ON p.productid=r.productid 
WHERE p.productname LIKE "%bean%" AND p.productname LIKE "%lemon%"
GROUP BY p.productid, p.productname
ORDER BY avgRating DESC
```

However, the LIKE search term is dynamic and so I have to use Criteria Builder.  I am able to write a Criteria Query without the join:

```py
public List<Product> dynamicQueryWithStringsLike(Set<String> searchSet
{
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
        Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);

        Path<String> productPath = product.get("productname");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : searchSet)
        {
            word = "%" + word + "%";
            predicates.add(cb.like(productPath, word));
        }

        query.select(product)
                .where(cb.and(predicates
                .toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

        return entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .getResultList();
}
```

But I am not very sure how to do it with a LEFT JOIN **and** return it with a Wrapper.
So far I have:

```py
public List<ReviewItem> testCriteria(Set<String> searchSet)
    {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ReviewItem> query = cb.createQuery(ReviewItem.class);
        Root<Product> productRoot = query.from(Product.class);
        Root<Review> reviewRoot = query.from(Review.class);
        Path<String> productPath = productRoot.get("productname");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : searchSet)
        {
            word = "%" + word + "%";
            predicates.add(cb.like(productPath, word));
        }

        Join<Product, Review> productReviewJoin = productRoot
                .join("productid", JoinType.LEFT);

        query
            .multiselect(
                productRoot.get("productid"), 
                productRoot.get("productname"),
                cb.avg(reviewRoot.get("stars")), 
                cb.count(reviewRoot.get("productid"))
                )
            .where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

        return entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

The current error I have is "Cannot join to attribute of basic type"
but I'm sure I have more than 1 error.  I've been reading the documentation, but I can't seem to find an example that uses a Join that returns a wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use cb.construct() for constructor based query
- join reviews using field name productReviews
- instead of reviewRoot use reviewJoin
- group by all non aggregated returning fields

  ```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<ReviewItem> query = cb.createQuery(ReviewItem.class);
  Root<Product> productRoot = query.from(Product.class);
  ...
  Join<Product, Review> reviewJoin = productRoot.join("productReviews", JoinType.LEFT);

  query.select(cb.construct(ReviewItem.class,        
                  productRoot.get("productid"),
                  productRoot.get("productname"),
                  cb.avg(reviewJoin.get("stars")),
                  cb.countDistinct(reviewJoin)
          ))
          .where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])))
          .groupBy(productRoot.get("productid"), productRoot.get("productname"))
          .orderBy(cb.desc(cb.avg(reviewJoin.get("stars"))));

  List<ReviewItem> x = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
  ```

ReviewItem:

```
public class ReviewItem {

Long getProductid;
String getProductname;
Double getAvgRating;
Long getReviewCount;

public ReviewItem(Long getProductid, String getProductname, Double getAvgRating, Long getReviewCount) {
    this.getProductid = getProductid;
    this.getProductname = getProductname;
    this.getAvgRating = getAvgRating;
    this.getReviewCount = getReviewCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It works!  I just had to change 2 things.  I changed ReviewItem fields to the nullable version to accommodate when Products didn't have Reviews.  Also count to countDistinct as it was returning an incorrect amount for the review count (it was returning the review count multiplied by total review count)